# Spring File downolad - httpServeletResponse null header and content type

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a view in my spring web application in which the user can downolad files stored in the server where the project is hosted.
So, in this view, I browse a list of files whose information are displayed in a table and the last column contains a link to downolad the file.
My problem that  for few files the HttpServletResponse content type and header are sent with null values and even if they were set in the function in the controller, the browser shows a response of type application/octet-stream.

In my jsp page:

```
<a href="<spring:url value='/download/${file.fileid}'/>"><i class="fa fa-download" title="download"></i></a>
```

And this is the code of the downolad function in the class Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/download/{fileid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void download(@PathVariable Integer fileid,  HttpServletResponse response)
    {

        File file = new   File((directoryService.findBydata("feedback").getPath()).trim()+"\\"+ (fileservice.findByfileid(fileid).getfilename()).trim());
        InputStream fis;    
        if(file.exists()){
             try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(fis, response.getOutputStream());
                                response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

                    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment; filename="+(fileservice.findByfileid(fileid).getfilename()).trim());

                    response.flushBuffer();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
```

}

I can't find the cause of this issue, Any idea why this happens? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the functionality like optional file uploading for entity because if the files are not exist at server side then the your source code if condition fails and it returns httpServeletResponse null header and content type

Comment: Thak you for the reply, the files are genertaed by my application using apache POI. if the process is finished successefully, I save a file record in DB. To be 100% sure, I checked in the server and the files are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes to HttpServletResponse are only written to the response after the method exits.

Your code however immediately writes the contents of the file to the output stream. Therefore the client receives the data without appropriate headers in the beginning.

Try wrapping your input stream into InputStreamResource and return that.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/download/{fileid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> download(@PathVariable Integer fileid, HttpServletResponse response) {
    File file = new   File((directoryService.findBydata("feedback").getPath()).trim()+"\\"+ (fileservice.findByfileid(fileid).getfilename()).trim());
    if(file.exists()){
        try {
            InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = new InputStreamResource(fis);

            return ResponseEntity
                    .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename="+(fileservice.findByfileid(fileid).getfilename()).trim())
                    .body(inputStreamResource);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Gorazd for the quick answer. So for some files, the client recieves the response before the content type and the header are set. Right? I tried your code and it's working perfecty. Many many thanks!

Comment: Yes. And, as the name implies, headers are at the beginning of the HTTP response.